# Is there a method for removing negative values from an array?

Tags: ruby

If I have something like:

`numbers = [2, 88, 0.5, -23.55, 0, -45000]`

I would like to return

`[2, 88, 0.5, 0]`

Comment: A shout out to the `partition` method which will be able to give you two arrays of negatives and non-negatives respectfully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [select](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-select) or [reject](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reject)

```
numbers.select { |number| number >= 0 }
```

or

```
numbers.reject(&:negative?)
```

Comment: Do you think there's any difference in speed between the two?

Comment: I dont' think so. But that would matter only with very large arrays. is it your case?

Comment: Hmmm, perhaps not. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the mighty (but oft-overlooked and undervalued) [Enumerable#grep](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep):

```
numbers.grep 0..Float::INFINITY
  #=> [2, 88, 0.5, 0]
```

or

```
numbers.grep 0..1/0.0
```

Comment: Not a fan of the `0..` infinite range notation?